# Projection on a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If I have a convex set $ S$ and if I project an $ x$ onto $S$. Is it true that $x $ would project onto a unique element of $S$. Why? What would be considered different if the set $S$ was non-convex?

Comment: How do you define your projection? Nearest element?

Comment: I think I mean projection on normed spaces.

Comment: Sure, so you have a convex set in a normed space, and the proejction of a point $x$ onto $S$ is the nearest element of $x$ in $S$?

Comment: Yes. What other way would you want to define the projection?

Comment: For example, if I were to project x onto S then I would normally do: $ \min_S ||x-S||_2^2 $ or something of that sort.

Comment: @M.B. if you have a hint or an answer - I would be interested in looking at that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need $S$ to be closed.  For example, $S=(0,1)$ is convex but $2$ has no closest point in $S$.

The most general type of space where the closest point property (i.e. the projection uniquely exists) holds is a Hilbert space - look in any functional analysis text for the proof.  It doesn't hold generally for any normed space even if $S$ is convex - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35449/why-isnt-the-theorem-of-approximation-applicable-in-banach-spaces).

To see why convexity is essential, take $S=[0,1]\cup[3,4]$ and think about $x=2$.